# Absolute position after zooming

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have divs with `class="myDiv"`. I need to do this logic: on mouse over, I want to show a popup in the middle of the div.

For that I have the following:

```
$(".myDiv").mouseover(function () {
  positionDiv($(this).position().left + $(this).width() / 2, $(this).position().top + $(this).height() / 2);
});

function positionDiv(xPosition ,yPosition ) {
  $("#popupWindow").css("left", xPosition + "px");
  $("#popupWindow").css("top", yPosition + "px");
  $("#popupWindow").show();
}
```

The CSS:

```
.popupWindow{
  position:absolute;
  width:313px;
  height:383px;
  display:none;
}
```

This will position the popup window in the middle of the div on mouse over. Everything works great at this point.

However, if the website is zoomed in (using the browser zoom functionality), tHe position will get messed up. The popup window no longer appears in the middle of `myDiv`.

Any idea what might be the problem?

Edit:

For more info, if it is created and I zoom it, it is fine. But when I move my mouse to another `myDiv` and the new popup appears in a weird position. The left and top attribute of the Div are messing up.

Comment: You'll need to capture the `.resize()` event and make reference to your function.

Comment: Does it mess up when you zoom in AFTER it has been centered or if the page loads zoomed in?

Comment: no. If it is create and I zoom it it is fine. But then I move my mouse to another myDiv and the new popup appear in a weird position

Comment: @Ohgodwhy can you please give me tips on how to do that?

Comment: @Shikiryu myDiv was used for this question only :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You don't need JS for this:

http://jsfiddle.net/coma/6VUpS/1/

The key is to play with CSS and avoid JS calculations. The container div (myDiv) should be **position: relative**, the popup must be inside and **position: absolute**, top and left to 50% and using negative margins to center it (http://www.css-101.org/negative-margin/06.php).

Try avoiding JS for visual fanciness, only CSS ensures the correct position even on zoom since it's rendered by the browser.

**HTML**

```
<div class="myDiv">
    Hi!
    <div class="popupWindow">you are welcome!</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.myDiv {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #eee;
    margin: 50px 0;
    position: relative;
}

div.popupWindow {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -50px 0 0 -100px;
    width: 200px;
    line-height: 100px;
    background-color: #111;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
    pointer-events: none;
}

div.myDiv:hover > div.popupWindow {
    display: block;
}
```

Bonus track using a checkbox to click/tap/toggle popup and some fade in:

http://jsfiddle.net/coma/6VUpS/3/

More hacky:

http://jsfiddle.net/coma/6VUpS/

More complex example:

http://jsfiddle.net/coma/dHTHG/

Comment: In your "more complex example" i get a lot of jittering in the first 5 pixels before chat bubble shows up. Is that unavoidable? Like a sub pixel issue?

Answer (score 1):

I understand your problem and my solution is to put every object containing a pop up in pos relative and then set your pop up with those CSS :

```
.myPopUp{
    position:absolute;
    display : none;
    width:400px;
    height : 100px;
    margin-top : -50px;
    margin-left:-200px;
    background-color: red;
    top : 50%;
    left: 50%;
}
```

It will alway be centered.

Now i understand you have only 1 pop up for all your hoverable div. My trick is to save the pop up in a var and remove it from its parent container to append it in the hovered div like this :

```
var popUp = $('.myPopUp');

$('.myDiv').mouseover(appendPopUp);
$('.myDiv').mouseout(function(){popUp.css('display', 'none')});

function appendPopUp(){
    console.log(popUp.parent(), $(this))
    if(popUp.parent()[0] != $(this)[0]){
        popUp.remove();
        $(this).append(popUp);
    }
    popUp.css('display', 'block')
}
```

That should work, here's my fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/7EEZT/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
    var $md = $('.myDiv');
    positionDiv($md.position().left + $md.width() / 2, $md.position().top + $(this).height() / 2);
});
```

Comment: My issue is not when the window is resized it is after. after zooming everything has correct position but if I go mouse over the new calculated X and Y will be wrong even tho I specify the X and Y of the same div

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple css solution if you have a div with known height and width you can do same task with help of css only

```
.popupWindow {
    position:absolute;
    width:313px;
    height:383px;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin-left:-156px;/*half of width*/
    margin-top:-191px;/*half of height*/
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: what would happen when I change the top and left attributes in the function?

Comment: in css first you shift div 50% from top to the browser window after that with help of negative margin compensate that shifting.with help of left and top margin you can adjust the position of popup on screen if you want to popup always should be middle of window set the margin 1/2 of height and width. for more info pease visit this URL 
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/absolute-center-vertical-horizontal-an-image/

Comment: sorry but I want it to be in the middle of a div not of the window

Comment: yes it will also work with div, just set position:relative; to parent div of popup div and popup will be center with its parent div.

Comment: The popup div is used for multiple divs. When I mouse over a div I need to reposition the div to the hovered div. when repositionning I am changing the "left" and "top" attribute of the popup div to be at the center of the hovered div. in your solution I cannot change the left and right of the popup div. also it is not inside the div I want to center it to. Hope I was clear

Answer (score 0):

Go with position:relative and try this. It will solved your problem relate to position.

```
$(".myDiv").mouseover(function () {
 positionDiv( $(this).width() / 2, $(this).height() / 2);
});

function positionDiv(xPosition ,yPosition ) {
 $("#popupWindow").css("left","-" + xPosition + "px");
 $("#popupWindow").css("top", "-" + yPosition + "px");
 $("#popupWindow").show();
}
```

The CSS:

```
.popupWindow{
 position:relative;
 width:313px;
 height:383px;
 display:none;
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kishan6446/PdNkg/13/

Comment: you have to go with position : relative. Look on demo.